# What game is this city screen from?

Tags: game-identification

Source for the next image: https://twitter.com/MagdalenaDK/status/721291039034773504?s=09

[image]

The above image. Which was shared with me via twitter,  I thought looked interesting. My instinct tells me this is the city screen of a hero TBS game like heroes of might and magic, but I am not sure which one.

Which game is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of Googling would suggest the game is [Heroes of Might and Magic IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic_IV). I haven't played it, but the UI matches.

Comment: Yep, thats it. Sadly I played it a bit, you lost nothing ;)

Answer (score 1):

I tried searching for this game using Google Image Search by uploading the image there. It automatically entered `heroes 4` in the search field and the first results were pages leading to the game **Heroes of Might and Magic IV**.
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I was on mobile so that was a bit too tricky. I already struggled with extracting the image from the tweet.